# Variable success in verifying Tails

Tags: tails, verification

Since the introduction of the new Tails signing key, which I think was towards the end of 2015, I have had variable success in verifying my download of the Tails ISO file. For example, to verify the `tails-amd64-3.6.iso` file, I enter the command

```
gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verify tails-amd64-3.6.iso.sig tails-amd64-3.6.iso
```

which returns the informative message:

```
gpg: Signature made Tue 13 Mar 2018 11:41:20 AEDT
gpg:                using RSA key 0x3020A7A9C2B72733
gpg: Good signature from "Tails developers <tails@boum.org>"
gpg:                 aka "Tails developers (offline long-term identity key) <tails@boum.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: A490 D0F4 D311 A415 3E2B  B7CA DBB8 02B2 58AC D84F
    Subkey fingerprint: 2FAF 9BA0 D65B B371 F0BC  2D46 3020 A7A9 C2B7 2733
```

However, when I attempt the same with the `tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso` using the supplied signature file `tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso.sig`, using the command

```
gpg --keyid-format 0xlong --verify tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso.sig tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso
```

I get the following output:

```
gpg: Signature made Sat 17 Mar 2018 11:08:42 AEDT
gpg:                using ? key 0x90B2B4BD7AED235F
gpg: Can't check signature: unknown pubkey algorithm
```

What is going wrong, and what is it that I should have done, or be doing?

I realize that there is always the remote possibility that I have downloaded a fake Tails iso file. For what it is worth,

```
sha256sum --binary tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso
```

gives

```
826c8fc05a7fb04962c6a45350648fc9273bf98f8b19b2d5a491b440d78ecbf6 *tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso
```

NEW INFO ADDED 2018-03-23 : I have installed the Tails verification extension in Firefox, which verifies the download. However, I'd still be very interested to know why the `gpg` check fails (despite the same approach succeeding with the 3.6 ISO)

Answer (score 1):

The error "unknown pubkey algorithm" is a consequence of (a) the fact that on my machine, the `gpg` command defaults to using `gpg1`, (b) `gpg1` does not support the use of elliptic-curve cryptographic algorithms, and finally, (c)  the Tails version I was trying to verify was signed using an elliptic-curve algorithm. For a discussion about the history of `gpg`, see the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard).

The solution is to ensure that `gpg2` is used instead of `gpg1`. So, for example, the verification command would read

```
gpg2 --keyid-format 0xlong --verify tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso.sig tails-amd64-3.6.1.iso
```